# Merge 2 different xml elements into 1 xml element using new DomDocument

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

I have a XML file which looks like this:

frankly speaking I have no idea how those scripts worked.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <resource>
        <languages>
            <language>en</language>
            <page1>
                <full_content_text>Full Content Text 1</full_content_text>
            </page1>
            <page2>
                <full_content_text>Full Content Text 2</full_content_text>
    </page2>
 </languages>
 <languages>
    <language>tc</language>
    <page1>
        <full_content_text>Full Content Text tc version 1</full_content_text>
    </page1>
    <page2>
        <full_content_text>Full Content Text tc version 2</full_content_text>
    </page2>
 </languages>
 </resource>
```

I want to output look like this:

I want to merge the page1 and page2 elements to become page element

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <resource>
 <languages>
     <language>en</language>
     <page>
         <full_content_text>Full Content Text 1 Full Content Text 2</full_content_text>
     </page>
  </languages>
  <languages>
     <language>tc</language>
     <page>
         <full_content_text>Full Content Text tc version 1 Full Content Text tc version 2</full_content_text>
     </page>
  </languages>
 </resource>
```

Code look like this:

```
$xml = ('test.xml');
$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->load($xml);
$nodes = $dom->documentElement;
$data = $nodes->getElementsByTagName('languages');

foreach($data as $key => $row){

 $page1 = $row->getElementsByTagName('page1')->item(0);
 $page2 = $row->getElementsByTagName('page2');
 foreach($page2 as $res){

     echo '<pre>';
     print_r($res);
     echo '</pre>';

 }

 $page = $dom->createElement('page', 'Merge Page1 and Page2 Here');
 $row->appendChild($page);

}

$dom->save("merged.xml");
```

Comment: Show the code you tried

Comment: Actually I'm not sure about my code: 

$xml = ('test.xml');
$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->load($xml);
$nodes = $dom->documentElement;
$data = $nodes->getElementsByTagName('languages');

foreach($data as $key => $row){
 
 $page1 = $row->getElementsByTagName('page1')->item(0);
 $page2 = $row->getElementsByTagName('page2');
 foreach($page2 as $res){
 
  echo '<pre>';
  print_r($res);
  echo '</pre>';
  
 }
 
 $page = $dom->createElement('page', 'Merge Page1 and Page2 Here');
 $row->appendChild($page);

}

$dom->save("merged.xml");

Comment: Not having any idea does not qualify as a programming question. You need to show with which part exactly you have which concrete understanding and why it behaves differently despite all the resources you've read (+ named + referenced) so far and you have understood that it needs to make the code like you understand it but it still behaves different.

Comment: This is also related that the code is not originally yours. Contact the original author for your support and tutoring options.

Comment: It's not duplicate since i have different elements inside the parent that i need to merge in one element..

Comment: Event text in an XML document are nodes, so called text nodes. In your case you only need to append the second textnode. See the update in CAsimir et Hippolyte's answer it should show that.

Comment: i really don't know what's the big deal for this one..i just ask question since im just learning xml.. and so far there are people who really want to help, and im thankful for all of them...

Answer (score 1):

According to your code, you are not far the solution. This is how I will do it:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($xml);
$languagesTags = $dom->getElementsByTagName('languages');

foreach ($languagesTags as $languagesTag) {
    $txtNodes = $languagesTag->getElementsByTagName('full_content_text');
    $newTextNode = $dom->createTextNode($txtNodes->item(0)->textContent . ' '
                                      . $txtNodes->item(1)->textContent);
    $page1 = $dom->getElementsByTagName('page1')->item(0);
    $page2 = $dom->getElementsByTagName('page2')->item(0);

    $languagesTag->removeChild($page1);
    $languagesTag->removeChild($page2);
    $newPageTag = $dom->createElement('page');
    $newFullTextTag = $dom->createElement('full_text_content');
    $newFullTextTag->appendChild($newTextNode);
    $newPageTag->appendChild($newFullTextTag);
    $languagesTag->appendChild($newPageTag);
}
$xml = $dom->saveXML();

echo htmlspecialchars($xml);
```

Comment: it's work fine but <full_content_text> is missing...

Comment: @zriel: Indeed, It is corrected.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$xml = ('test.xml'); 
$dom = new DOMDocument(); 
$dom->load($xml);
$tags = $dom->getElementsByTagName('languages');

foreach ($tags as $tag) {
    $page1 = $tag->getElementsByTagName('page1')->item(0);
    $page2 = $tag->getElementsByTagName('page2')->item(0);
    $newNode = $dom->createElement('page');
    $tag->appendChild($newNode);
    $fullText = $dom->createElement('full_content_text');
    $newNode->appendChild($fullText);
    $page = $dom->createTextNode($page1->nodeValue.$page2->nodeValue);
    $fullText->appendChild($page);
    $tag->removeChild($page1);
    $tag->removeChild($page2);    

}

$dom->save("merged.xml");
```

Answer (score 0):

In php you can try function simplexml_load_file or simplexml_load_file_string
$xml=simplexml_load_file("xyz.xml");

Now parse the xml and get the "languages" element temporary store the page1 and page2 element into variable, unset those page1 and page2  element.
Now concat page1 and page2 variable.
Using addChild Function you can add  element to "languages"

After processing convert xml object into string using asXML()
And save this string to a xml file.

I hope this may help you to build the logic.