# Combine two elements in XML file

Tags: php, xml

First off thanks for any help!

I have an xml that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE tv SYSTEM "xmltv.dtd">

<tv source-info-url="http://tvschedule.zap2it.com/" source-info-name="zap2it.com" generator-info-name="zap2xml" generator-info-url="zap2xml@gmail.com">
<channel id="I16689330.labs.zap2it.com">
    <display-name>502 WCBSDT</display-name>
    <display-name>502</display-name>
    <display-name>WCBSDT</display-name>
    <icon src="https://zap2it.tmsimg.com/h3/NowShowing/16689/s28711_h3_aa.png" />
</channel>
<programme start="20180303203000 -0500" stop="20180303230000 -0500" channel="I20453335.labs.zap2it.com">
    <title lang="en">NBA Basketball</title>
    <sub-title lang="en">Boston Celtics at Houston Rockets</sub-title>
    <desc lang="en">From the Toyota Center in Houston.</desc>
    <category lang="en">Sports</category>
    <category lang="en">Basketball</category>
    <length units="minutes">120</length>
    <icon src="https://zap2it.tmsimg.com/assets/p14464724_tb2_v5_aa.jpg" />
    <url>https://tvlistings.zap2it.com//overview.html?programSeriesId=SP00371600&amp;tmsId=SP003716000000</url>
    <episode-num system="dd_progid">SP00371600.0000</episode-num>
    <new />
    <subtitles type="teletext" />
</programme>
</tv>
```

I would like to generate something like this that combines title with sub-title:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE tv SYSTEM "xmltv.dtd">

<tv source-info-url="http://tvschedule.zap2it.com/" source-info-name="zap2it.com" generator-info-name="zap2xml" generator-info-url="zap2xml@gmail.com">
<channel id="I16689330.labs.zap2it.com">
    <display-name>502 WCBSDT</display-name>
    <display-name>502</display-name>
    <display-name>WCBSDT</display-name>
    <icon src="https://zap2it.tmsimg.com/h3/NowShowing/16689/s28711_h3_aa.png" />
</channel>
<programme start="20180303203000 -0500" stop="20180303230000 -0500" channel="I20453335.labs.zap2it.com">
    <title lang="en">NBA Basketball: Boston Celtics at Houston Rockets</title>
    <desc lang="en">From the Toyota Center in Houston.</desc>
    <category lang="en">Sports</category>
    <category lang="en">Basketball</category>
    <length units="minutes">120</length>
    <icon src="https://zap2it.tmsimg.com/assets/p14464724_tb2_v5_aa.jpg" />
    <url>https://tvlistings.zap2it.com//overview.html?programSeriesId=SP00371600&amp;tmsId=SP003716000000</url>
    <episode-num system="dd_progid">SP00371600.0000</episode-num>
    <new />
    <subtitles type="teletext" />
</programme>
</tv>
```

If it can be done with a php script that would preferable

Comment: That's some pleasant XML you've got there. What about code? Did you pick a language and try to solve this problem yet?

Comment: If it can be done in PHP I would be able to swing that. This topic is similar and maybe could be tweaked to my situation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25028634/merge-2-different-xml-elements-into-1-xml-element-using-new-domdocument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if we have the XML string in `$string`, we can parse it into an XML object with `simplexml_load_string`:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);
```

And then access elements as object properties:

```
> echo $xml->title;
NBA Basketball
```

To build your desired combined property, it is as intuitive as (note how the dash special character must be handled):

```
$xml->title .= ': '.$xml->{'sub-title'};
```

Because we have combined the sub-title attribute into title, we no longer need it:

```
unset($xml->{'sub-title'});
```

And then print the whole object:

```
> echo $xml->asXML();
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<programme start="20180303203000 -0500" stop="20180303230000 -0500" channel="I20453335.labs.zap2it.com">
    <title lang="en">NBA Basketball: Boston Celtics at Houston Rockets</title>

    <desc lang="en">From the Toyota Center in Houston.</desc>
    <category lang="en">Sports</category>
    <category lang="en">Basketball</category>
    <length units="minutes">120</length>
    <icon src="https://zap2it.tmsimg.com/assets/p14464724_tb2_v5_aa.jpg"/>
    <url>https://tvlistings.zap2it.com//overview.html?programSeriesId=SP00371600&amp;tmsId=SP003716000000</url>
    <episode-num system="dd_progid">SP00371600.0000</episode-num>
    <new/>
    <subtitles type="teletext"/>
</programme>
```

Sample complete execution:

```
<?php 
$string = file_get_contents('xmltv.xml'); 
$xml = simplexml_load_string($string); 
$xml->title .= ': '.$xml->{'sub-title'}; 
unset($xml->{'sub-title'}); 
file_put_contents('xmltv.xml', $xml->asXML());
?>
```

Comment: Is it possible to use this process by loading the original .xml file into the script and output a new file?

Comment: Sure. An easy way to do that would be with `$string = file_get_contents($sourceFileName)` and `file_put_contents($destFileName, $xml->asXML())`

Comment: '<?php
  $string = file_get_contents($xmltv.xml)
  $xml = simplexml_load_string($string);
  > echo $xml->title;
  $xml->title .= ': '.$xml->{'sub-title'};
  unset($xml->{'sub-title'});
  file_put_contents($xmltv.xml, $xml->asXML())
?>'

Comment: Almost. Modified slightly, tested to verify, and added to answer.

Comment: You are amazing but I am dumb and didn't post enough info about the xml. I edited the original post. Tried it on the original text I posted and it worked but it seems that something goes wrong in the larger context of the xml file

Comment: gmail chat
sharpshooter2k3 @ the G

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, consider [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/Style/XSL/), the special purpose language designed to transform XML files. PHP can run XSLT 1.0 with its [php-xsl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xsl.php) class (be sure it is enabled in .ini file). Also, XSLT is portable and does not need PHP to run it. Most other languages (Java, Python, Perl, VB) can run such scripts and even standalone [XSLT processors](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt/info).

Specifically, below XSLT script runs the Identity Transform to copy document as is and then rewrites the *programme* node with `concat()` of *title* and *subtitle*, finally reproducing all else nodes and attributes. While this may seem overkill, if your XML is much larger and maintains many *programme* nodes this XSLT will combine ALL *title* and *sub-title* without any looping.

**XSLT** *(save as .xsl file, a special .xml file)*

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!-- IDENTITY TRANSFORM -->
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">  
        <xsl:copy> 
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- REWRITE PROGRAMME -->
    <xsl:template match="programme"> 
        <xsl:copy>     
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <title><xsl:value-of select="concat(title, ' ', sub-title)" /></title>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*[name()!='title' and name()!='sub-title']" /> 
        </xsl:copy>       
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**PHP**

```php
$xml = new DOMDocument;
$xml->load('Input.xml');

$xsl = new DOMDocument;
$xsl->load('XSLT_Script.xsl');

// Configure transformer
$proc = new XSLTProcessor;
$proc->importStyleSheet($xsl);

// Transform XML source
$newXML = new DOMDocument;
$newXML = $proc->transformToXML($xml);

// Output to console
echo $newXML;

// Output to file
file_put_contents('Output.xml', $newXML);
```

**Output**

```
<programme start="20180303203000 -0500" stop="20180303230000 -0500" channel="I20453335.labs.zap2it.com">
  <title>NBA Basketball Boston Celtics at Houston Rockets</title>
  <desc lang="en">From the Toyota Center in Houston.</desc>
  <category lang="en">Sports</category>
  <category lang="en">Basketball</category>
  <length units="minutes">120</length>
  <icon src="https://zap2it.tmsimg.com/assets/p14464724_tb2_v5_aa.jpg"/>
  <url>https://tvlistings.zap2it.com//overview.html?programSeriesId=SP00371600&amp;tmsId=SP003716000000</url>
  <episode-num system="dd_progid">SP00371600.0000</episode-num>
  <new/>
  <subtitles type="teletext"/>
</programme>
```