# Loop through an XML file using powershell and merge one field into another

Tags: xml, powershell

I have an XMLTV file that I would like to add the *sub-title* (episode name) node to the *desc* for each *programme* listing so that the *desc* tag looks like this ->

`<desc lang=en>Episode Title: Episode description.</desc>`

This is an extract from the XML file that I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<tv>
    <programme start="20180228110000 +0000" stop="20180228120000 +0000" channel="21558">
        <title lang="en">Forged in Fire</title>
        <sub-title lang="en">Talwar</sub-title>
        <desc lang="en">With just five days to recreate the sacred but lethal Talwar sword, which smith will defy all odds to claim the title of Forged in Fire Champion and a 10,000 dollar prize?</desc>
        <credits>
            <producer>Tim Healy</producer>
            <presenter>Wil Willis</presenter>
        </credits>
        <category>Reality</category>
        <category>Series</category>
        <category>series</category>
        <episode-num system="xmltv_ns">3.6.</episode-num>
        <episode-num system="dd_progid">EP023535090040</episode-num>
        <previously-shown start="20170516120000 +0000"/>
        <rating system="Australian Classification Board">
            <value>PG</value>
        </rating>
        <rating system="Canadian Parental Rating">
            <value>PG</value>
        </rating>
        <rating system="R&#xE9;gie du cin&#xE9;ma">
            <value>G</value>
        </rating>
        <rating system="Freiwillige Selbstkontrolle der Filmwirtschaft">
            <value>12</value>
        </rating>
        <rating system="USA Parental Rating">
            <value>TVPG</value>
        </rating>
    </programme>
</tv>
```

I am trying to use Powershell so that I can set it as a scheduled task each night, what I have so far is this:

```
$in = 'C:\Downloader\XMLTV\Guide\SchedulesDirect\guide.xml'
$out = 'C:\Downloader\XMLTV\Guide\SchedulesDirect\guide1.xml'
$xml = (Get-Content $in)

ForEach ($Node in $in.tv.programme) {
    $in.tv.programme.desc = $in.'tv.programme.sub-title' + $in.tv.programme.desc
    Set-Content $out
}
```

I don't seem to be having much luck with it even after following a few things on here, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This question seems uncannily similar to this recent [XML TV post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49021329/1422451) but that one needs to combine *title* and *sub-title*. Classmates? Co-workers? Friends?

Comment: Yes it does seem similar, I was hoping to use powershell though if possible so it can run as a scheduled task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read the file as an `XmlDocument` to be able to loop nodes. The loop would also have to loop nodes in the xml-object (not the input-path) and reference the current node inside the scriptblock. Try:

```
$in = 'C:\Downloader\XMLTV\Guide\SchedulesDirect\guide.xml'
$out = 'C:\Downloader\XMLTV\Guide\SchedulesDirect\guide1.xml'

#You should parse the file as an XmlDocument-object
$xml = [xml](Get-Content $in)

#Template-node for desc
$DescExample = $xml.SelectSingleNode('//programme/desc').Clone()
#The xml-picture in comments didn't show lang="en" on all programme-nodes, so new desc-nodes are created without
$DescExample.RemoveAllAttributes()

#Loop programme-nodes in the XmlDocument-object
ForEach ($Node in $xml.tv.programme) {

    if($Node.'sub-title') {
        if($Node.desc) {
            #Set desc for each node to "Sub-Title: Desc"
            $Node.desc.InnerText = "{0}: {1}" -f $Node."sub-title".InnerText, $Node.desc.InnerText
        } else {
            #Desc-element missing. Will create one
            $newdesc = $DescExample.Clone()
            $newdesc.InnerText = $Node.'sub-title'.InnerText
            $Node.AppendChild($newdesc) > $nul
        }
    }    
}

#Save document when all nodes are modified, not inside the loop
$xml.Save($out)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I don't think I ever would have managed to put that together myself, unfortunately I am getting errors when I run it though:

The property 'InnerText' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
At line:9 char:5
+     $Node.desc.InnerText = "{0}: {1}" -f $Node."sub-title".InnerText, ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyAssignmentException

Comment: Are you sure the xml is correct? That `desc` doesn't have subnodes? Which PS-version?

Comment: Hi, it is PSVersion 5.1.16299.248. Yes the <sub-title> node and the <desc> node are both sub nodes of <programme>. Basically the guide programme I have doesn't have the ability to display <sub-title> so I want the episode name in the description when it is available. Thanks

Comment: Oh and obviously there are hundreds of <programme> nodes, one for each listing.

Comment: I can't reproduce the error. Are you the xml sample is correct? I duplicated the programme-node while testing. `InnerText` is a valid property, but you can try to replace all `InnerText` with `'#text'`, ex. `$Node."sub-title".'#text'`

Comment: Tried it using '#text' and it throws up the same error. This is a screenshot of the xml file, it has a list of the channels first and then the programme listings start, you can see the first one at the bottom. https://gyazo.com/d07e07ab8ad14c17d0199a06b48e08c3

Comment: The screenshot doesn't help unfortunately. The error complains about `Innertext`, which means that the problem probably is in or below the desc-element.

Comment: This is the first <programme> node: https://gyazo.com/f8ddbffe36eb731f941a65ea154f71b3

Comment: That should work. The problem is most likely that one or more of the programme-nodes doesn't have a `desc`-element. See updated answer

Comment: Hi, that seems to still be throwing up the same error, I have looked through the XML file and it looks like the desc element is present for each entry, although there are a lot of shows so I can't be certain, the sub-title is definitely not present in each one though. But even when I strip all the programme entries out bar two that have both sub-title and desc it still throws up the error like I still get errors with this XML file: https://gyazo.com/5ac73b5a9844a598982df408c26b91c8

Comment: Updated to ignore programme-nodes without sub-title. Tested against complete sample found here http://wiki.xmltv.org/index.php/XMLTVFormat and still works fine. If you still can't get it to work, try another computer (PS version) or wait for someone else to answer here. I'm out of ideas

Comment: Hi, thanks for that, I have added the lang="en" to each of the title. sub-title and desc nodes and then script works without any errors so looks like you were right about the problem being the XML file, now I just need to figure out how to add lang="en" to each of the nodes before I run it, thank you so much!